# plotting a function in 3d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to plot functions within the simplex, but every time I add a function in the usual 2d plot way i get an error. How can I add a function of two variables, for example x^2+y^2 =0.5, here is the example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (1,0,0);
\coordinate (P) at (0,1,0);
\coordinate (Q) at (0,0,1);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[thick,color=red] (O) -- (P);
\draw[thick, color=red] (P) -- (Q);
\draw[thick, color=red] (Q) -- (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**update**
I tried with a different piece of code, but I still cannot write in a function of two different variables:

```
    \documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view/h=135,
      axis lines=center,
      xmax=1.5, 
      ymax=1.5,
      zmax=1.5,
      ytick={1},
      xlabel={$x_{1}$},
      ylabel={$x_{2}$},
      zlabel={$x_{3}$},
    ]
    \addplot3[patch,blue!70!black!50,forget plot] 
      coordinates 
      {
      (1,0,0) 
      (0,1,0) 
      (0,0,1)
      };
    \addplot3[no markers,red!90!black] 
      coordinates 
      { 
      (0.25,0.1,0.45) 
      (0.2,0.1,0.4) 
      (0.24,0.36,0.4) 
      (0.16,0.32,0.62) 
      (0.12,0.3,0.58) 
      (0.1,0.26,0.64) 
      };
      \addplot3[domain=0:2, red, thick] {x^2+y^2};

    \node[fill=red!90!black,inner sep=1pt,circle,label={180:$Y$}] 
      at (axis cs:0.1,0.26,0.64) {};  
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

For example, here I did x^2, which works, but I want to write y^2 for example which doesnt work, or z^2.. or any function of two variables. Note: the x^2 isn't actually the graph i want but im just trying to get the code to work for any function of two variables

[image]

**update 2** I had forgotten to use \addplot3, it seems to be working now.